# Casting datatypes

Tags: java, types, casting, integer, typecasting-operator

// ( i'm trying to cast From Float to Integer Value )

```
public class Genark
{
static <T extends Number , E extends Number > void add ( T o2 )
{
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
E e2 = (E) o2; // it is must be casted to integer ( but something went wrong )

System.out.println( e2.getClass().getName() ); // java.lang.Float ( it is not casted )
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

Genark.<Float , Integer>add( 6.2f );

}
```

/**************************** I want to do something like that ************************/

```
float y = 6.2f;
int x = (int) y;
System.out.println( x);   // here it is casted to Integer Successfully

}
}
```

Comment: While you can cast `float` to `int`, you can't cast `Float` to `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

`float` -> `int` and `Float` -> `Integer` are two different conversions that involves different types. Note that `Float` and `Integer` are the boxed versions of `float` and `int` respectively. In a casting context, the former is allowed and the latter is not:

```
float x = 0f;
Float y = 0f;
int a = (int)x; // OK
Integer b = (Integer)y; // error;
```

The `Float` -> `Integer` conversion actually consists of 3 smaller conversions - the `Float` needs to be unboxed, narrowed, then boxed again.

```
Float -unbox-> float -narrowing-> int -box-> Integer
```

This is not allowed in a casting context. See a list of allowed conversions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5).

On the other hand, `float` -> `int` is just a simple narrowing conversion.

---

That said, this doesn't really matter in your code because you wrote a *unchecked cast* (notice the unchecked warning!), which does nothing at runtime. This is because you are casting to the generic type parameter `E`, and the JVM won't know what the actual type for `E` is at runtime because of [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens). This is why there is no error at runtime or compile time.

The cast will only happen when you do some `Integer`-specific things to `e2`, but there is no way to do that within `add`, and you don't return `e2` either, so nothing substantial happens.

For the sake of illustration, let's say you have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer x = add(1f);
    System.out.println(x.compareTo(2));
}

static <T extends Number , E extends Number > E add ( T o2 )
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E e2 = (E) o2;
    return e2;
}
```

Then it will crash at runtime when trying to call `x.compareTo(2)`, an `Integer`-specific method.